# Is there a concrete description of relative jet spaces that invokes neither internal Hom nor individual generators?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be $S$-schemes. Define the sheaf $\underline{\hom}_S(Y,X)$ on $S$-schemes by $\underline{\hom}_S(Y,X)(T) := \hom_S(T \times_S Y,X)$. In other words, we have

$\hom_S(T,\underline{\hom}_S(Y,X))\cong \hom_S(T \times_S Y,X)$,

which explains the name: If this sheaf is representable, it is the internal hom object. It coincides with the Weil restriction $\mathfrak{R}_{Y/S}(X \times_S Y)$ (see *Néron models* by BLR). Grothendieck mentions in FGA 5, C.2, that $\underline{\hom}_S(Y,X)$ has only a chance to be representable when $Y$ is flat and proper over $S$. So my first question is: where Grothendieck actually proved this result?

I claim that $\underline{\hom}_S(Y,X)$ is representable whenever $Y \to S$ is finite locally free and a universal homeomorphism: one just has to look at the proof for Weil restrictions in Theorem 7.6/4 in BLR; the condition on the fibers of $X$ is not needed. In particular this holds for $Y=S[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^{n+1}$ for some $n \geq 0$, which is the example which interests me.

For example, we have $\underline{\hom}(S,X) = X$ and $\underline{\hom}(S[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2,X) = T(X/S) = \mathbb{V}(\Omega^1_{X/S})$ is the tangent bundle of $X/S$. This is just a reformulation of the universal properties, but there is a sort of global description of $\Omega^1_{X/S}$, namely as $I / I^2$, where $I$ is the kernel of the multiplication $\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_S} \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$. My **main question** is: Is there any such global description for
$$T^n(X/S) := \underline{\hom}(S[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^{n+1},X)$$? 
Probably this is what people call the $n$-th jet bundle, but I could not find any concise description in the literature. Remark that we have a seqeunce of morphisms 
$$\dotsc \to T^n(X/S) \to T^{n-1}(X/S) \to \dotsc \to T(X) \to X.$$ 
The proof of the Theorem in BLR works roughly as follows: Everything is local on $S$, to suppose it is affine. If $X$ is some affine space, you can find explicitly a representing scheme. More generally, for every quasi-coherent module $M$ on $S$ and $\mathcal{A}$ the quasi-coherent algebra on $S$ corresponding to $Y \to S$ which is finite locally free, we have $\underline{\hom}_S(Y,\mathbb{V}(M)) = \mathbb{V}(\underline{\hom}_{\mathcal{O}_S}(\mathcal{A},M))$. This implies $T^n(\mathbb{A}^m/S) \cong \mathbb{A}^{m(n+1)}$. If $X$ is affine, embed it into some affine space. If $X$ is arbitrary, glue everything. So this description is not really global and even depends on affine charts on $X$ and choices of generators and relations on the affine charts.

This can be done here even more explicit: Assume that $S=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Let $A^{(n)}$ be the $A$-algebra generated by symbols $h_i(a)$ for every $0 \leq i \leq n$ and $a \in A$, subject to the following relations:

- $h_0(a)=a \cdot 1$
- $h_i(1)=0$ for $i \geq 1$
- $h_i(a+b)=h_i(a)+h_i(b)$
- $h_i(ab)=\sum_{p+q=i} h_p(a) h_q(b)$

Then $T^n(X/S) = \mathrm{Spec}(A^{(n)})$. The morphism $T^n(X/S) \to T^{n-1}(X/S)$ is induced by the obvious homomorphism $A^{(n-1)} \to A^{(n)}$ which inserts the generators. This description is well-known for $n=1$, where $h_1$ is just a derivation with respect to $h_0$.

I am **not** looking for a reference about jet spaces or alike. I would like to know if we can construct some sort of "concrete" $A$-algebra out of the $R$-algebra $A$ which turns out to be isomorphic to $A^{(n)}$. For example, when $n=1$, the well-known answer is the symmetric algebra of $I/I^2$, where $I = \ker(A \otimes_R A \to A)$, with $h_1(a)=a \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes a$.

Comment: Note: Two days ago I had asked a similar question, which I have deleted because it was not phrased well enough. I've tried to improve it.

Comment: It is the jet space.  One reference (not the original) is the following article of Looijenga.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0006220.pdf


Comment: Ok so my question is if there is any global description of jet bundles (not jet spaces, these are just the fibers). There is a lot of material about jet bundles and jet spaces, but they don't seem to address my question.

Comment: Typically the things you are calling "jet bundles" are not smooth over the base, so I think you should not call them bundles.  Whether or not you think the name is appropriate, traditionally the schemes representing these functors are called "jet spaces".

Comment: Could you please be more explicit what you mean by "global description"?  There is actual important mathematics about global properties of the jet spaces, cf. the many important papers of Demailly on the Green-Griffiths-Lang conjecture.  But I do not know precisely what it is you are looking for.

Comment: A global description would be something which is constructed via kernels, cokernels, tensor products etc. out of $R \to A$. I am not interested in global properties, just another representation of the definition of $A^{(n)}$ which does not use generators and relations. In the end, I would like to transport all that to the realm of $2$-algebraic geometry ...

Comment: See also the following recent paper by R. Moosa and T. Scanlon: 
"Jet and prolongation spaces", Journal of the Inst. of Math. Jussieu (2010) 9 (2), 391--430.

Comment: It might help to change the title to something like "Is there a description of relative jet spaces that invokes neither internal Hom nor individual generators?"

Comment: (+1) This is something I've been asking about for a while.  Here is another thing one could desire: there is a grading on $A^{(n)}$ coming from scaling $\epsilon$.  Is there an intrinsic description that makes this grading manifest?  Again, the $n=1$ case is clear, it's the natural grading on the symmetric algebra.  (Also, to second Jason Starr's comment about the name, there's an unfortunate clash of terminology: "jet bundle" typically refers to something else---the infinitesimal neighborhoods of diagonals for smooth schemes.)

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, I think the answer depends on whether you think representability means "in schemes" or "in algebraic spaces".  For schemes, you really want a projective morphism $Y \to S$ for BLR's proof to work.  For spaces, I think Olsson's "Hom stacks and restriction of scalars" gave a proof using flat proper and lfp.  (I don't see any conditions on the fibers in $X$ in your question.)

For your other questions, see [Vojta](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407113).

Comment: For $Y$ a flat, proper, lfp algebraic space over $S$, the result goes back to Artin's "Algebraization and Formal Moduli, I" (he also requires $Y$ to be locally finitely presented).

Comment: In BLR $Y/S$ is assumed to be finite locally free. The article by Vojta is a great reference for jets, thank you! They arrive at the same conclusions as at the end of my question. However, they don't give a global description of $\Omega^{(n)}_{A/R}$, and therefore don't answer my question.